# windows 2003 remote desktop configuration - "Active session limit" greyed out

Tags: rdp

I have a terminal server which works fine except for one thing: users are logged off after 2 hours, regardless of activity. I have Override user settings checked in the appropriate control window, and "End a disconnected session: Never" is set. But, I found the "Active session limit" is greyed out so I can't change it, and is set to 2 hours. The user (only 1 actually needs a session on this server for more than 2 hours at a time) is able to reconnect to his session immediately.

http://the-wes.com/images/active-session-disabled.jpg

Any ideas?

thanks,
-wes

Answer (score 1):

If the setting on the server is unavailable then it's being set by GPO. Take a look at the settings that are configured in the GPO that's linked to whichever container or OU where the server's computer object is.

Comment: any idea where in the great big tree of Group Policy options that could be found?

Comment: found it. gpedit.msc -> computer configuration -> administrative templates -> windows components -> terminal services -> sessions -> "sets a time limit for active terminal services sessions" - it was set to enabled. I flipped it to disabled. now the settings page looks right. hopefully the actual disconnects will stop happening too! thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...